# Symfony Form: как сохранить JSON?

Tags: json, symfony, doctrine, symfony4, doctrine-orm

Даны три связанных сущности:`Question` - вопросы анкеты, `Options` - варианты ответов на вопросы анкеты,`Answer` - ответы на вопросы анкеты.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\QuestionRepository")
 */
class Question
{
    // ...
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Answer", mappedBy="question")
     */
    private $answers;

    /**
     * @Groups({"question"})
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Options", mappedBy="question")
     */
    private $options;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->options = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->answers = new ArrayCollection();
    }
    // ...
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\OptionsRepository")
 */
class Options
{
    // ...
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Question", inversedBy="options")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $question;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Answer", mappedBy="options")
     */
    private $answers;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->answers = new ArrayCollection();
    }
    // ...
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\AnswerRepository")
 */
class Answer
{
    // ...
    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Groups({"answer"})
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="answers")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @Groups({"answer"})
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $text;

    /**
     * @Groups({"answer"})
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Options", inversedBy="answers")
     */
    private $options;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Question", inversedBy="answers")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $question;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->options = new ArrayCollection();
    }
    // ...
}
```

**App\Form\AnswerType:**

```
class AnswerType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('text')
            ->add('user')
            ->add('question')
            ->add('options', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Options::class,
                'multiple' => true
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Answer::class,
            'csrf_protection' => false
        ]);
    }
}
```

Нужно сохранить результаты опроса в сущность `Answer`
Как мне обработать это POST-запрос? JSON отправляется при submit. Каждый ответ на вопрос это вложенный объект JSON.

```
[
    {
        "question": "1",
        "user": "1",
        "text": "",
        "options": [
            "1",
            "2",
            "3"
        ]
    },
    {
        "question": "2",
        "user": "1",
        "text": "text",
        "options": [
            ""
        ]
    },
    {
        "question": "3",
        "user": "1",
        "text": "",
        "options": [
            "4"
        ]
    }
]
```

В итоге каждый этот вложенный объект JSON (question, user, text, options) должен стать строкой с заполненными колонками (qustion_id, user_id, text) в таблице Answer. То есть свойство объекта json `question` должно занять место в колонке `question_id` в таблице `Answer` и так далее.

**UPD:**
Сделал таким образом до лучших времен.

```
/**
 * @Rest\Post("/answer")
 */
public function postAnswerAction(Request $request)
{

    $data = $request->request->all();

    foreach ($data as $item) {
        $answer = new Answer();

        $form = $this->createForm(AnswerType::class, $answer);
        $form->submit($item);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($answer);
            $em->flush();
        }

    }

    return $this->handleView(
        $form->getErrors(true)->count() > 0
            ? $this->view($form->getErrors(true))
            : $this->view(['status' => 'created']
            , Response::HTTP_CREATED, ['Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*'])
    );
}
```

Comment: Обратите внимание на DataTransformer для question  и для options ибо почти наверняка форма ожидает id в соответствующих полях. Хотя если это у вас и является id , тогда это работать будет.

А по сути вам нужно json в массив, потом итерируете, создаете в каждой итерации Answer заполняете через форму данными (используете напрямую submit) и через EntityManager записываете в базу данных.

Ну и не забываете что это все делается не в контроллере, а создаете отдельный сервис для этого, например.  :)

Comment: Да, это и есть id. Имеете в виду что-то вроде этого [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/954n1W1F)? Так работает, но что-то мне не нравится мое решение))

Comment: @ОлегНечаев в вашем примере, на пастебине, вполне все верно, однако, вы обращаетесь к базе в каждом цикле, попробуйте так https://pastebin.com/2fADvgpi